# Why is “Y penses-tu?” correct and “Penses-y tu?” wrong?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots, interrogative

I was solving a [test](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/pron_adverbial.htm) on *y* vs. *en*, and there was a question:

> Penses-tu à ton chien ?
>
> 1. En penses-tu ?
> 2. Y penses-tu ?
> 3. Penses-en tu ?
> 4. Penses-y tu ?

and I choose *"Penses-y tu?"* (I had no solid reason for that, but I remembered I saw verb-y formations before, so that “felt” right to me) but the right answer was *"Y penses-tu?"*

Can you explain to me why is *"Y penses-tu?"* a better choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pronouns always come before the verb in French:

> Tu y penses.
>   Tu me le donnes.

Except for two cases:

- In a question with inversion, the subject pronoun goes after the verb and is attached to it with a hyphen:

  > Y penses-tu ?
  >   Me le donnes-tu ?
- In the imperative form, the verb comes first and the pronouns follow (also attached to it with one or more hyphens). Note that in the imperative there is no subject.

  > Penses-y !
  >   Donne-le-moi !

Comment: @Alexis: Bien vu, il y a bien un *s* artificiel qui s'ajoute à l'impératif spécialement pour le pronom *y*, et qui sert juste à transcrire la liaison. (Et quand on y pense… quelle horreur !)

Comment: Y a-t-il des sources pour "*donne-moi-le !*" ? J'ai toujours entendu dire aux enfants : on dit "*donne-le moi !*"

Comment: Tout à fait en bon français on dirait « donne-le-moi », mais si on faisait des statistiques à l'oral…